# Bars in histogram are tiny (regarding width) and overlapping. How to increase bar width of matplotlib plot.hist()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a 3 histograms in the same plot and my values for the x-axis are in range from 0-256 which yields to tiny bars regarding the width and the bars are also overlapping. How can I increase the width of the histogram in general or the width for each bar?

```
plt.hist((a, b, c), 255, range=(0, 255), normed=True, label=['a', 'b', 'c'] rwidth=2)
```

I have tried `rwidth` but that did not work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars should not be overlapping when not using `rwidth`. The width of the bars is determined by the number of bins (in this case 255). Using less bins would make the bars wider.

The `rwidth` keyword argument determines the relative width of the bars. When making it larger than 1, bars will overlapp. That is the indendet functionality, so don't use it, or make it smaller than 1 to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Of course further help could be provided with a [mcve] of the issue in the question.

Comment: Well even when I have not used `rwidth` the bars were not overlapping but there were some white regions in between the bars even though each bin has a value greater than zero

Comment: That would be a different problem. But in any case, without a  [mcve] of the issue (best accompanied with the resulting image) it's really hard to help here.